# Let ABC be acute angled triangle with AB =15 cm and BC=8 cm

Tags: geometry

Let ABC be acute angled triangle with AB =15 cm and BC=8 cm.let D be point on AB such that BD=BC. consider E on AC such that angle DEB =angle BEC. if x denotes the product of all possible values of AE, find x.

[image]

when i am considering cyclic quadilateral am not able to solve

Comment: Your equation is an identity, your result for $x$ is wrong.

Comment: could you solve it correctly?

Comment: somebody plz help.

Comment: @Arentino you are right. it is becoming identity.

Comment: i am just able to proceed till AE= 15k, EC=8k

Answer (score 1):

The problem, as stated, has infinite solutions. If you take ANY triangle $ABC$ with $AB=15$ and $BC=8$, construct point $D$ on $AB$ such that $BD=8$ and draw the bisector $BE$ of angle $B$, then you have a perfectly valid triangle.

As the triangle is acute-angled, then $AE$ can take any value between ${15\over23}\sqrt{161}\approx 8.275$ (case when $\angle BCA=90°$) and 
${15\over23}17\approx 11,087$ (case when $\angle ABC=90°$).

I don't know if that could mean anything, in view of the strange request about "the product of all possible values of $AE$", which could have sense if only integer values for $AE$ were allowed. If that is the case, then the possible integer values for $AE$ are: $9$, $10$ and $11$.

Comment: at ABC=90 i am not getting your value.

Comment: if $\angle ABC=90°$ then $AC=\sqrt{15^2+8^2}=17$